# Magento2 Overload a phtml from an other module - Best way

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

is it possible to overload a phtml from an other module?

For example:

[image]

I want to overload the multiple-select.phtml in an own Module
( MyVendor/MyNs )

The multiple-select.phtml is called by class from the manadev module:

[image]

Now, my idea is to rewrite the "TextMultipleSelect" Class by using the di.xml:

```
<preference for="Manadev\LayeredNavigation\FilterTemplates\Dropdown\TextMultipleSelect" type="MyVendor\MyNs\FilterTemplates\Dropdown\TextMultipleSelect" />
```

And then redefine in class:

```
MyVendor\MyNs\FilterTemplates\Dropdown\TextMultipleSelect
```

the Method getFilename like this:

```
public function getFilename(Filter $filter) {
    return 'MyVendor_LMyNs::filter/multiple-select.phtml';
}
```

Is this the correct way?

( It works for me ... but i want to know the BEST way )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation [says](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-override.html#override) that the right way to override template is to create a custom theme and override a template in it.

However, if we say about an ability to change a behavior of the class, another page of documentation [says](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ext-best-practices/extension-coding/common-programming-bp.html#composition-over-inheritance) you should prefer composition over inheritance. And the topic you're looking for is a ["Plugins"](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html), especially "around" plugins

Comment: Ok! did it with adding it in my custom theme. But what happens if i want to add a new Block INSIDE of this file? Do i have than move it in my custom module?  Is the plugin solution better than extending ?

Comment: If you need to extend existing block, you, of course, should extend it. It's better to use Plugins (and composition), but sometimes it's not enough.
Regarding your question, there is another documentation link ["Common layout customization tasks"](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html) which says that if you need to manipulate with blocks, you may choose another way than creating custom theme - customize block configuration or replace that block.

Comment: However, if you want just to change a behavior of several public methods and plugins may cover your case - use them as it's most non-destructive and customizable way to extend some behavior.